# Does project centennial have any problems converting applications that were built using unsafe mode?

Tags: c#, unsafe, desktop-bridge

I have built a Win32 application using C#. Some of the code contains a binding for a native dll but is written using unsafe code, will project centennial allow the conversion of this part of the installation-CRL code?

Answer (score 1):

I've never had issues writing managed code with native dlls imports, it wouldn't hurt to post your code.

But to answer your question, it should compile just fine.